# SPDY CDN + Async Script-loading backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, spdy, labjs

Would async script loaders like [LABjs](https://github.com/getify/LABjs) or [$script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js) prove beneficial, neutral, or negative if already using a CDN supporting SPDY?

1. I'm going to use a full-site CDN with SPDY, for example Cloudflare
2. I've read [Script-injected "async scripts" considered harmful](https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/) but thanks to jQuery dependencies I need to control execution order.
3. I want to keep dependencies as unbundled as possible

i.e. I've got a series of JS scripts where `<script src=` would work fine and `<script async src=` would not. I don't want sync because it would be blocking. And `defer` is too flaky to consider.

Given the above, I would use a script loader without second thought if it weren't for the uncertainty of SPDY. I probably just need to know whether the approach used by these scripts still gets the same SPDY benefits (pipelining, compression, etc) as "regular" approaches?

Another way of framing the question is: what would be the impact of switching from synchronous script loading with SPDY CDN to using async script loaders with SPDY CDN?

Answer (score 0):

I've had very bad performance issues using Cloudflare as a SPDY proxy, and my benchmarks went from 1.5 seconds to about 4 seconds over SPDY (266% slower).  You should test yourself, and you should see faster results with direct connections to your server.

CDN's would slow you down, because SPDY allows all resources to be pulled from **one** socket connection, and a CDN (https) would require multiple TLS handshakes and round-trip connections which could slow your site down.

This test shows about 350 resources loaded via SPDY, and you won't get those results with a CDN: http://httpvshttps.com/

Here's an interesting article:

https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/why-we-dont-use-a-cdn-spdy-ssl/

Comment: The article is interesting but irrelevant - they were testing a CDN with no SPDY support at the time.

Comment: Please explain why "a CDN (https) would require multiple TLS handshakes and round-trip connections" is true. Are you considering the case where someone has www.site.com and cdn.site.com for static resources?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  > 1 TLS handshake would slow things down.

Comment: That's why I mentioned "full-site CDN", i.e. the CDN serves www.site.com and there is no extra hostname. i.e. 0 extra TLS handshakes and you get the benefit of SPDY too. I don't know if there's an accepted technical term for this but if you search "full-site CDN" or "full-site delivery CDN" then you'll find nearly all major CDN providers discussing their solution.

Comment: Yes, that would perform very well.